# High voltage and low voltage sensing via the same pin

Tags: avr

I am trying to put together a high-voltage programmer for AVR, which involves applying 12V to the target's nRESET in an otherwise 5V system. However, I also want to use nRESET for presence sensing from the host through its built-in pullup (which gives about 4.2V through a DMM).

Obviously when the 12V is applied I need to allow it through to the target but clamp it before it reaches the host. I was wondering if the following was a sane way to do so or if I missed sometime crucial:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feqpvh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The actual host and target will be an ATtiny2313V and ATtiny85 respectively, but for purposes of this exercise we can assume that both will be [ATmega328Ps](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf).

Comment: I'd feel safer using a 4.7V zener.

Comment: I was thinking an NPN common base, with emitter at !RESET, base at ~4V and collector at Psense, but that'd probably require some fiddl'ing with other values (R3 for example) too. But the transistor will probably break down and avalanche when you attach 12V.

Comment: @jippie: Yeah, the 2N3904 and 2N2222 break down at 6V so I'd have to use something a bit more exotic.

Comment: If /psense is okay, maybe a 2N7000 with series gate resistor and BAV99 dual diode clamp to 0V and +5.